# Smarty strip tags not working

Tags: smarty, strip

Is there a particular reason why {strip} tags in smarty don't work? I have two templates. In one of them, it works. In the other it doesn't. But I put them in the exact same place

```
{strip}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-// W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
......
</html>
{/strip}
```

I would just like to know what are the possible causes to this.

Comment: "{strip} is not effecting subtemplates as it is a compile time process and subtemplates are compiled independent from the calling ones (and may be shared)." - http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=69734&sid=e128ab294c994b55137b1e3de47eacd4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have improperly nested or improperly closed Smarty tags elsewhere on the page, it could be breaking the `strip` pair, since they're the outermost pair.

Leaving something like `{literal}` unclosed or having a syntax error that's causing the page to stop rendering before the end of the page (view source; do you have the whole source, up to and including the final `</html>` tag?) would cause the final `{/strip}` to not get included/evaluated.